# Regex with inputmask for commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

```
$("#xyz").inputmask('Regex', {regex: "^[0-9]{1,8}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$"});
```

Above expression allows me to enter 8 digits and 2 decimals but it doesn't automatically handle commas. Can any one help me with commas.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is a bit wrong, this should work instead:

```
^[0-9]{1,8}([,.][0-9]{1,2})$
```

It will accept up to 8 digits and then a comma or dot, followed by up to another 2 digits.

Edit: This regex requires commas, decimals are optional. Maximum is 999,999,999, minimum is 0.00

```
^([0-9]{0,3}|0)(,[0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{3})?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Comment: my output with $("#xyz").inputmask('Regex', {regex: "^[0-9]{1,8}(\\.\\d{1,2})?$"}); is 23444444.55 but im expecting 23,444,444.55

Comment: @Nain Do you always expect commas? Or should 23444444.55 and 23,444,444.55 both be valid? You should edit your post with some examples of what you expect should be valid and what shouldn't.

Comment: if its 100 I expect 100 but for 1000 I expect 1,000 for 297312984 i expect 29,731,298 so on....So if i have a number in 1000s or higher I always expect commas.

Comment: @Nain I've edited my original answer, it should now be what you want.

Comment: @moidal I tried $("#rateOfPay").inputmask('Regex', {regex: "^([0-9]{0,3}|0)(,[0-9]{3})?(,[0-9]{3})?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$"}); but didn't work it just allowed me to enter 6 digits i.e. 123456 with no decimals and commas